# Apache Cassandra 3.10 IllegalArgumentException - Invalid token for Murmur3Partitioner

Tags: java, cassandra, yaml, virtualbox, cluster-computing

The token value that I'm using:

```
initial_token: 85070591730234615865843651857942052864
```

Is causing the following Java exception when I try to start Cassandra:

```
Exception (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) encountered during startup: Invalid token for Murmur3Partitioner. Got 85070591730234615865843651857942052864 but expected a long value (unsigned 8 bytes integer).
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token for Murmur3Partitioner. Got 85070591730234615865843651857942052864 but expected a long value (unsigned 8 bytes integer).
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$2.fromString(Murmur3Partitioner.java:333)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$2.validate(Murmur3Partitioner.java:317)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyInitialTokens(DatabaseDescriptor.java:885)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:321)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:141)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:646)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:581)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:735)
ERROR [main] 2017-03-01 19:57:15,861 CassandraDaemon.java:752 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token for Murmur3Partitioner. Got 85070591730234615865843651857942052864 but expected a long value (unsigned 8 bytes integer).
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$2.fromString(Murmur3Partitioner.java:333) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$2.validate(Murmur3Partitioner.java:317) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyInitialTokens(DatabaseDescriptor.java:885) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:321) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:141) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:646) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:581) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:735) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
```

Cassandra starts fine on my first node with `initial_token: 0`

What am I doing wrong?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My main question would be why are you trying to set it?

That token (`85070591730234615865843651857942052864`) is likely for the random partitioner, not murmur partitioner. Can check other nodes in your cluster but perhaps set in the cassandra.yaml:

```
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner
```

Murmur3 partitioner is better idea though, not sure where you got that token or why you expect it to work. Is better to let it assign tokens itself if your just adding nodes. Just do not set it.

```
# initial_token:
```

Comment: I was following [this](http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/how-to-set-up-and-monitor-a-multi-node-cassandra-cluster-on-linux) guide that specified generating and setting the intial_tokens for each machine. Is this information now dated and I should be doing this a different way?

Comment: yeah thats 5 years old ;) thats for before vnodes, which you can still do if you set `num_tokens:1`. but just dont bother if using vnodes (default)

Comment: So I don't need to change any of the token related settings. I just leave `num_tokens: 256` uncommented?